# GoogleMaps like marker with place name around the marker

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

GoogleMaps like marker with place name around the marker, the reason I say around because the name moves around the marker with respect to other markers around it & sometime it even hides the name if marker get too close to each other. I have seen other solution on how to show the name with the marker but their the name position is fixed.

[image]